# Get top n values including duplicates with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, c#-7.0

Please consider this list:

```
City            Value
---------------------
City1             10
City2             20
City3             30
City4             40
City5             50
City6             60
```

If I want to get top 3 Values in Cities I can write this `LINQ`:

```
MyList.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Value).Take(3);
```

Now consider this list:

```
City            Value
---------------------
City1             10
City2             20
City3             30
City4             40
City5             50
City6             60
City7             60
```

I want a query that return all cities with top **3** highest values. For above list I want this result:

```
City            Value
---------------------
City7             60
City6             60
City5             50
City4             40
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var result = MyList.GroupBy(o => o.Value)
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
                   .Take(3)
                   .SelectMany(g => g)
                   .ToList();
```

This list will contain all cities with the top 3 highest values, sorted in descending order by value.

Answer (score 0):

A bit clunky, this solution finds the third highest DISTINCT value, then returns all values equal or greater to it.

```
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

var MyList = new List<(string, string)>();
MyList.Add(("City1", "10"));
MyList.Add(("City2", "20"));
MyList.Add(("City3", "30"));
MyList.Add(("City4", "40"));
MyList.Add(("City5", "50"));
MyList.Add(("City6", "60"));
MyList.Add(("City7", "60"));
var topThreeDistinct = MyList.Distinct(new StringStringComparer()).OrderByDescending(o => o.Item2).Take(3).ToList();

var thirdValue = topThreeDistinct[2].Item2;
Console.WriteLine($"Third value = {thirdValue}");

var topThreeAll = MyList.Where(o => o.Item2.CompareTo(thirdValue) >= 0 ).ToList();
foreach (var item in topThreeAll)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");

class StringStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<(string, string)>
{
    public bool Equals((string, string) x, (string, string) y)
    {
        if (x.Item2 == y.Item2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        };
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] (string, string) obj)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(obj.Item2);
    }
}
```

(C# .NET 6.0 Console App)